# Installed 12.04 from CD - won't boot

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, grub2, boot-repair

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 from a CD on a Toshiba Portege laptop. The installation process seemed to go normally, but now when I try to boot it, it hangs at the "Toshiba Leading Innovation" screen. Booting from the CD does work (which is what I'm doing now).

The installation wizard says that there is a 12.04 partition on /dev/sda2. I checked that the BIOS's boot order is HDD first. With the installation CD in the drive, I can get to a grub menu by pressing Esc, but I don't know what to do with it. I tried installing Boot-Repair using the instructions here (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), but am getting the following error:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
boot-repair boot-sav boot-sav-extra gawk glade2script
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 44 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource
temporarily  unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I did remove the installation CD when prompted to reboot.

EDIT EDIT: I ran boot-repair from an Ubuntu-secure-remix live USB, and got the following result: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1691369/ The boot-repair process seemed to go normally, but the computer still doesn't boot.

SOLUTION: For future reference, the problem turned out to be that the BIOS was in UEFI mode. I switched it to CSM mode and reinstalled, and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[zeptoweasel](https://askubuntu.com/users/133727/zeptoweasel) solved it in [his question](https://askubuntu.com/q/258519/44179):

> SOLUTION: For future reference, the problem turned out to be that the BIOS was in UEFI mode. I switched it to CSM mode and reinstalled, and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once, What I did was reinstalled again when the installation is done a message will come up saying press enter to restart make sure that the CD or whatever source of installation is removed and then reboot when the computer boots it should work fine every time I leave the CD in i get stuck in the black screen just like you.
 Hope this helps